# Minimal distance between intersections of a regular grid parameterized by its change-of-basis matrix

Tags: euclidean-geometry, integer-programming, combinatorial-geometry

Let a 2D grid basis $\mathcal{B}(\theta_1, \theta_2,r_1, r_2)$ whose change-of-basis matrix with respect to $\mathcal{B}_0$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ writes :
$$P_{\mathcal{B}_0}^{\mathcal{B}(\theta_1, \theta_2,r_1, r_2)} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
    r_1\cos(\theta_1)     & r_2 \cos(\theta_2) \\
    r_1\sin(\theta_1)     & r_2 \sin(\theta_2) 
    \end{array}\right)$$

and the parameters of the grid satisfy
$$
\begin{array}[ccc]
&&\\
\theta_1 & \in & (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]\\
\theta_2 & \in & [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \theta_1)\\
r_1,r_2 & > & 0
\end{array}
$$
The intersections of the grid $\mathcal{B}(\theta_1, \theta_2,r_1, r_2)$ written in $\mathcal{B}_0$  is the following set
$$ \left\lbrace P_{\mathcal{B}_0}^{\mathcal{B}(\theta_1, \theta_2,r_1, r_2)}  z\;;\;\forall z\in \mathbb{Z}^2\right\rbrace$$

Given this setting, computing the minimal distance between two intersections of this grid is equivalent to solving the following problem
$$\min_{z\in\mathbb{Z}^2_*}\|P_{\mathcal{B}_0}^{\mathcal{B}(\theta_1, \theta_2,r_1, r_2)}  z\|_2$$

Where $\mathbb{Z}^2_*=\mathbb{Z}^2\setminus \lbrace (0,0)\rbrace$. The solution of this problem can be tricky to compute in corner cases. For example, let the grid be as follows:
$$r_1 = 2\;;\;r_2=5\;;\;\theta_1 = -10^° \;;\;\theta_2 = -11^°$$
With this configuration the minimal value for  $\|P_{\mathcal{B}_0}^{\mathcal{B}(\theta_1, \theta_2,r_1, r_2)}  z\|_2 $ is achieved for $z^*=(5,-2)$.

Finally, my question is, is there a faster method than Integer Programming to solve this problem. Particularly I would like to know if there is a way to compute $z_i^-$, $z_i^+$ such that
$$\textrm{arg}\min_{z\in \mathbb{Z}^2_*}\|P_{\mathcal{B}_0}^{\mathcal{B}(\theta_1, \theta_2,r_1, r_2)}  z\|_2 \subset[z_1^-,z_1^+]\times[z_2^-,z_2^+] $$

Comment: Please review and edit your question. You talk about the minimum distance between two grid points but compute the minimum norm of a single grid point. The grid point with minimal norm will always be $(0,0)$, so I assume that is not what you really want.

Comment: Please note that the minimum is sought over $\left(\mathbb{Z}^*\right)^2$ which excludes $(0,0$. Let $\mathbb{Z}^2 \ni z_1 \neq z_2 \ni   \mathbb{Z}^2$, then $z_-z_2 \in \left(\mathbb{Z}^*\right)^2$. The problem is therefore well posed.

Comment: Please give an explicit definition of $\mathbb{Z}^*$, which is unfamiliar notation.